# Is there a more succinct/elegant way to find and select a particular ComboBoxItem by its content?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, foreach, combobox

I'm in the process of reducing the size, and increasing the efficiency, of a C#.NET 4.0 desktop application, and I've come across some code that finds a combobox's item based on its content (a string) and selects it as the default. The combobox is dynamically populated, so the index of that particular item can change, and the string itself can have changing cases, so the search needs to be case-insensitive. Here's the code:

```
foreach( ComboBoxItem item in myComboBox.Items )
{
    if( item.Content.ToString().Equals( "myString", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) )
    {
        myComboBox.SelectedItem = item;
    }
}
```

I would just like to know if there is a faster and/or more elegant way to do this. Like, is there a one-liner I could use to reduce these three lines and/or speed up the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't know the case of the string, but you know the string itself, I would just use linq:

```
myComboBox.SelectedItem = myComboBox.Items.Cast<ComboBoxItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Content.ToString().Equals("myString", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: This will not handle CurrentCultureIgnoreCase string comparison

Comment: @SimonMourier As I said, provided you know the case of the string. The fact that he is capitalizing "myString" made me think it was a fair assumption, but I stated it anyway.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response, user3690202, but my myComboBox.Items doesn't have a possibility for FirstOrDefault. Am I missing something else to use that? I've included System.Linq.

Comment: @Lazovis - I assume you have using System.Collections.Generic? What version .NET does the app target?

Comment: @Lazovis - Sorry, I missed a Cast<>() call in there - that should work for you now.

Comment: @Lazovis Updated as requested - glad it helped.